# How to protect Doorkeeper route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-4.2, doorkeeper

I'm using the Doorkeeper gem in a Rails 4.X app. Is there a way to protect the route for managing Oauth applications?

For example, I'd like this URL http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications to be available to the Devise users that are flagged as admins.

My current routes.rb looks like this.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

 use_doorkeeper
 devise_for :users
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Doorkeeper can handle in it's initializer. Just add this and it works.

```
 admin_authenticator do
   redirect_to new_user_session_url unless current_user && current_user.admin?
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with devise you can do something like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  # the same would be authenticate :user, -> (u) { u.admin? } do
    use_doorkeeper
  end
end
```

This suggests that your `User` respond to `admin?` method.

Comment: Yes. But the best solution I think it's to use the logic in the doorkeeper initialized. Fixed the issue. Thanks for you answer, gonna try that too. :)

Comment: It surely works (I have just tested for myself). Yes, if the gem allows to configure it in initializer it would be proper solution.